# Android: RecyclerView layout problem when list goes off the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have an activity where a test (questions with their corresponding possible answers on each fragment) is displayed.

The question is displayed and immediately below the possible answers are displayed with a RecyclerView.

If the question is short and the answers fit on the screen no problem is found, but the problem appears as soon as the question is longer and the RecyclerViews answers goes off the screen.

The issue apparently is RecyclerView's height is not properly calculated and it takes as its height the remaining space between the question bottom and the screen bottom, so if you scroll down you get a cut RecyclerView and only scrolling again inside of it fixes partially the problem.

This is my layout where you can see the RecyclerView:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTestMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llBody"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llTestHeader"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvQuestionNumber"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#4572ab"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llZoom"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_gravity="end">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvZoom"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/cbAndImage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llTvQuestion"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|start"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <WebView
                                android:id="@+id/webViewQuestion"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:scrollbars="none"
                                android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llTvImgInstructions"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingStart="10dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvImgInstructions"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textIsSelectable="false" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/cbLayout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:scrollbars="none"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:visibility="invisible"
                                android:id="@+id/rv" />

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llExplanations"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:paddingTop="20dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <WebView
                                android:id="@+id/webViewExplanations"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </ScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llVerticalPager"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffff"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/llFetchingdata"
            layout="@layout/testme_fetchingdata" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

And this is how I set the RecyclerView in code:

```
private void createRecyclerView_TestMode(int pageNumber, TestDTO test)
{
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    
    RecyclerView rv = tBinding.rv;
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    RVAdapter_Test_QuestionAnswers adapter =
            new RVAdapter_Test_QuestionAnswers(pageNumber, test, tBinding, Enum.CallingActivity.Test);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Generally recyclerview does not behave nice when nested inside inside of a scroll view. Maybe you can try using `NestedScrollView` instead but I'm not sure if that's going to help.

Comment: You are a genius @Pawel. I really need a ScrollView because answers may go off the screen, but replaced ScrollView by androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView and it's apparently working fine, so if you write it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you very much!
PS. I have to say I've only tested in an Android 10 mobile, I hope it will work on older Android devices.